# Perspective Transform in OPENCV PYTHON

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to perform a perspective transform of a sudoku puzzle. The expected transformation is happening only on the left side. Please help me by pointing out my mistake.

Input Image:

[image]

Expected Output Image:

[image]

The output I am getting:

[image]

The corners of the sudoku puzzle found using **cv2.approxpolydp()** are as follows:

```
top_left = [71,62]
top_right = [59, 418]
bottom_right = [443, 442]
bottom_left = [438, 29]
```

The shape of the output image is [300,300].

The corresponding output coordinates are :

```
output_top_left = [0,0]
output_top_right = [0, 299]
output_bottom_right = [299, 299]
output_bottom_left = [299,0]
```

The following is the code I used for perspective transform:

```py
#corners = [[71,62], [59, 418], [443, 442], [438, 29]]
new = np.float32([[0,0], [0,299], [299,299], [299,0]])
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32(corners), new)
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(gray, M, (300,300))
```

The  generated Transformation Matrix is :

```
[[ 9.84584842e-01  3.31882531e-02 -7.19631955e+01]
 [ 8.23993265e-02  9.16380389e-01 -6.26659363e+01]
 [ 4.58051741e-04  1.45318012e-04  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have your X,Y coordinates reversed. Python/OpenCV requires them listed as X,Y (even though you define them as numpy values). The array you must specify to getPerspectiveTransform must list them as X,Y.

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read input
img = cv2.imread("sudoku.jpg")

# specify desired output size 
width = 350
height = 350

# specify conjugate x,y coordinates (not y,x)
input = np.float32([[62,71], [418,59], [442,443], [29,438]])
output = np.float32([[0,0], [width-1,0], [width-1,height-1], [0,height-1]])

# compute perspective matrix
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(input,output)

print(matrix.shape)
print(matrix)

# do perspective transformation setting area outside input to black
imgOutput = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (width,height), cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(0,0,0))
print(imgOutput.shape)

# save the warped output
cv2.imwrite("sudoku_warped.jpg", imgOutput)

# show the result
cv2.imshow("result", imgOutput)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Hi frmw42, can we automate the perspective transform that is it possible to detect the X, Y coordinates automatically

Comment: Sorry,  am not sure I understand your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: If you are asking how to get the corners of the input image, then the simplest method would be to extract contours and find the contour of the largest rectangle -- the outline of the sudoku puzzle. Then use approxPolyDP() to get get a quadrilateral and use the 4 corners of the quadrilateral. An other way, would be to register the puzzle to another puzzle that was already face-on using SIFT or ORB to find corresponding control points. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html

Comment: What can be done if I want to warp only into a small section of the destination image, which is not rectangular, but is defined by 4 corners? I don't see `warpPerspective` is able to take in a mask, or ROI limits to only perform inverse-warp there. How does one approach this?

Comment: Warp the whole image and crop. Or make transparent outside to the size of the input and warp that.

Comment: As per your comment in the code I tried x,y,w,h but it got me horizontally flipped image ..... so I made it y,x,h,w now it's working good

Comment: That is likely because you did not follow my note in the code "# specify conjugate x,y coordinates (not y,x)" when setting up your control points for np.float32 or you did not order your control points in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that:

1. Coordinate are reversed: width, height
2. Destination is scaled:
   First Place Ratio: width/height
   Second Place Ratio: height/width
3. Order of points coordinate do not matter but Source and Destination points should be correspondent to each other.